# How to validate "Select" tag in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="#" class="group" method="post" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
    <legend><span class="number">1</span>Departing & Arriving</legend>
    <fielset class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="FDestination">From</label>
        <select name="Location" id="Location">
            <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
            <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
            <option value="Mahdi">Mahdi</option>
            <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
            <option value="Cilo">Cilo is</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
    function checkforblank(){
        if (document.getElementsByID('Location').value== "Please Select") {
            alert('Please enter first name');
            document.getElementById('Location').style.borderColor = "red"; 
            return false; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I display error when user chooses "Please Select" option from fieldset?

Comment: There is a typo in your post. document.getElementsByID('Location').value should be document.getElementById('Location').value

Comment: @Payson I'd suggest posting this as the answer. Also, try to take a look into using dev tools in whichever browser you are using to test the code. This would be a great asset in saving time and frustration in the future :)

Comment: @LukeG thanks. Good tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I display error when user chooses "Please Select" option from fieldset?

You are already validating form submit, now you only need to add the same validation function for select `onchange`:

```js
function checkforblank() {
    
    var location = document.getElementById('Location');
    var invalid = location.value == "Please Select";
 
    if (invalid) {
        alert('Please enter first name');
        location.className = 'error';
    }
    else {
        location.className = '';
    }
    
    return !invalid;
}
```

```css
.error {border: 1px red solid;}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="group" method="post" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
    <legend><span class="number">1</span>Departing & Arriving</legend>
    <fielset class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="FDestination">From</label>
        <select name="Location" id="Location" onchange="checkforblank()">
            <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
            <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
            <option value="Mahdi">Mahdi</option>
            <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
            <option value="Cilo">Cilo is</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

<sub>You will not see alert in demo, as it's not allowed in snippet sandboxed iframe :(</sub>

Comment: Thankyou very much! ,  say if I had another select option with exact same options and value also ID's how can i make the data validate there aswell? should I just create a process for that part again or is there a shorter way for me to use exact same validation without having to write another process again.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the `required` keyword? Requires HTML5, but doesn't need to rely on JS. For additional info, see [the documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element).

```css
:required:focus {
  box-shadow: 0  0 6px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  border: 1px red solid;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="group" method="post" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
  <legend><span class="number">1</span>Departing & Arriving</legend>
  <fielset class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="FDestination">From</label>
    <select name="Location" id="Location" required>
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
      <option value="Mahdi">Mahdi</option>
      <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
      <option value="Cilo">Cilo is</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

After noticing that this wasn't working well on all browsers, or on all inputs I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjw1dyox/1/) with many input types (but not all HTML5 ones are included). This way, you can check if the `required` attribute is working in the browsers that you need. At this time, a JS might indeed be your best bet to be completely cross-browser safe.

Comment: You can also add disabled and hidden keywords to make the "Please select" option unclickable. <option selected disabled hidden value="">Please select</option>

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validateForm() {    
  if (document.getElementById('Location').value== "Please Select")
  {
      alert('Please enter first name');
      document.getElementById('Location').style.borderColor = "red"; 
      return false; 
  }    
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="#"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<select name="Location" id = "Location" >
  <option value = "Please Select" >Please Select </option>
  <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
  <option value="Mahdi">Mahdi</option>
  <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
  <option value="Cilo">Cilo is </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Click">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure HTML solution:

make your select tag required,
make your first option selected, disabled, and add the value attribute and leave it empty: (`value=""`), if they don't choose anything, it throws a frontend validation error asking them to change the value since it is empty.

```html
        <select required name="Location" id="Location">
            <option disabled selected value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
            <option value="Mahdi">Mahdi</option>
            <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
            <option value="Cilo">Cilo is</option>
        </select>
```